# How to enlist children of specified Parent in treeview colum (table)

Tags: grails-plugin, grails

I am newbie in grails and tried to implement treeview using RichUI plugin, which shows all parents with individual children in Parent.list.gsp

**xml for parent and their children**

```
     <parents name='Parents'>
  <Parent id='1' name='Parent_1'>
    <Children name='Children'>
      <child name='Child_2' id='2' />
      <child name='Child_4' id='4' />
      <child name='Child_1' id='3' />
      <child name='Child_3' id='1' />
    </Children>
  </Parent>
  <Parent id='2' name='Parent_2'>
    <Children name='Children'>
      <child name='Child_1' id='8' />
      <child name='Child_2' id='7' />
      <child name='Child_4' id='6' />
      <child name='Child_3' id='5' />
    </Children>
  </Parent>
</parents>
```

**Parent Domain Class**

```
class Parent {

String name

static hasMany = [children:Child]
```

}

**Child Domain Class**

```
class Child {

    String name
    Parent parent

    static belongsTo = [parent:Parent]

}
```

**Parent Controller**

```
def list = {

    def writer = new StringWriter()
    def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
    xml.parents(name: "Parents"){
        Parent.list().each {
            Parent parentt = it
            Parent( id:parentt.id,name:parentt.name) {
                Children(name:'Children'){
                    parentt.children.each {
                        Child childd = it
                        child(name:childd.name,id:childd.id)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(!params.max)params.max=10
    ["data":writer.toString(),parentInstanceList: Parent.list(params), parentInstanceTotal: Parent.count()]
}
```

**Parent.list.gsp**

```
 <head>
    <resource:treeView/> ...</head>

 <body>
   <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <g:sortableColumn property="id" title="${message(code: 'parent.id.label', default: 'Id')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="name" title="${message(code: 'parent.name.label', default: 'Name')}" />
                        <g:sortableColumn property="relationship" title="${message(code: 'parent.relationhsip.label', default: 'Relationship')}" />

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <g:each in="${parentInstanceList}" status="i" var="parentInstance">
                    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">

                        <td><g:link action="show" id="${parentInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: parentInstance, field: "id")}</g:link></td>
                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: parentInstance, field: "name")}</td>
                        <td><richui:treeView  xml="${data}" /></td>

                    </tr>
                </g:each>
                </tbody>
            </table>

 </body>
```

**Problem**

Currently, in list view, every Parent entry has list of all parents and their children under
relationship column

Parent List view Snapshot [link text](http://img232.imageshack.us/img232/6326/parentlistview.png)

**Question**

how can i enlist all children only for each parent instead of enlisting all parents with their children in each Parent entry ?

thanks in advance

Rehman

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is you are rendering the XML for all the nodes in one operation and then passing it to 'data' which displays the same XML for every row.

what you need to do is pass a parameter of the parent id into the closure:

/* this gets run on the foreach loop in your gsp*/

```
def listParentNode = {
def parentId = params.id
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
xml.parents(name: "Parents"){
    Parent.findAllById(parentId).each {
        Parent parentt = it
        Parent( id:parentt.id,name:parentt.name) {
            Children(name:'Children'){
                parentt.children.each {
                    Child childd = it
                    child(name:childd.name,id:childd.id)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

["data":writer.toString()]
//or render "data" as XML // depending on what the richui tag is expecting.
}
```

the other peice  is in your gsp, leave the gsp file intact just change this part:

```
<td><richui:treeView  xml="${createLink(controller:'somecontroller',action:'listParentNode', id: parentInstance.id )}" /></td>
```

somecontroller is the name of your controller where these actions are.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

I have altered both parent.list.gsp and parentController as suggested in your reply. But
this approach generated a NullPointerException 

[http-8080-1] ERROR richui.TreeViewTagLib  - Error parsing xml
    java.lang.NullPointerException
     at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:33)
     at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parseText(XmlSlurper.java:215)


I have tried to debug parentController and ended with no clue.
do you have any idea how can i deliever/get right results ?

Comment: could you post your newly modified controller action and the gsp code?

Comment: i dont know how to format the code properly in "add comment" function thats why i have uploaded a pdf and you can have a look on document http://pdfcast.org/pdf/source-code . if you are unable to understand following code

Comment: def list = {

  if(!params.max)params.max=10
  [parentInstanceList: Parent.list(params), parentInstanceTotal: Parent.count()]
 }

Comment: def listParentNode = {
  println(params)
  def parentId = params.id
  def writer = new StringWriter()
  MarkupBuilder  xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
  xml.parents(name: "Parents"){
   Parent.findAllById(parentId).each {
    Parent parentt = it
    Parent( id:parentt.id,name:parentt.name) {
     Children(name:'Children'){
      parentt.children.each {
       Child childd = it
       child(name:childd.name,id:childd.id)
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
     ["data":writer.toString()]
  //or render "data" as XML // depending on what the richui tag is expecting.
 }

Comment: <g:each in="${parentInstanceList}" status="i" var="parentInstance">
      <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
                            <td><g:link action="show" id="${parentInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: parentInstance, field: "id")}</g:link></td>

                            <td>${fieldValue(bean: parentInstance, field: "name")}</td>
                            <td>
                          <richui:treeView  xml="${createLink(controller:'parent',action:'listParentNode', id: parentInstance.id )}" />
                         </td>
                        </tr>